# Pass struct to other contract

Tags: solidity

I'm using one contract to interact with another.

I made a simple example, when I do it like this, it works!!

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract Create {

    mapping(uint256 => string) public quote;
    mapping(uint256 => bool) public exists;

    function set(uint256 ID) external {
        quote[ID] = "test";
        exists[ID] = true;
    }
}

interface ICreate {

    function quote(uint256 ID) external view returns (string memory);
    function exists(uint256 ID) external view returns (bool);

    function set(uint256 ID) external;
}

contract MyContract {
    function setQuote(address CreateAddress, uint256 ID) external {
        ICreate(CreateAddress).set(ID);
    }

    function getQuote(address CreateAddress, uint256 ID) external view returns (string memory _quote, bool _exists) {
        _quote = ICreate(CreateAddress).quote(ID);
        _exists = ICreate(CreateAddress).exists(ID);
    }
}
```

[image: successful test]

But when I try to put two pieces of information inside a struct, it doesn't work:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract Create {

    struct Quote {
        string quote;
        bool exists;
    }

    mapping(uint256 => Quote) public quote;

    function set(uint256 ID) external {
        quote[ID] = Quote("quote", true);    }
}

interface ICreate {
    struct Quote {
        string quote;
        bool exists;
    }

    function quote(uint256 ID) external view returns (Quote memory);

    function set(uint256 ID) external;
}

contract MyContract {
    function setQuote(address CreateAddress, uint256 ID) external {
        ICreate(CreateAddress).set(ID);
    }

    function getQuote(address CreateAddress, uint256 ID) external view returns (ICreate.Quote memory _quote) {
        _quote = ICreate(CreateAddress).quote(ID);
    }
}
```

```
decoded output  {
    "error": "Failed to decode output: Error: data out-of-bounds (length=32, offset=64, code=BUFFER_OVERRUN, version=abi/5.5.0)"
```

Can anyone tell me what is happening?
This is the error that appears in the remix, I don't understand it right.

Comment: Their is a simple mistake mate.
You are defining quote function in the interface but not in the `create` contract

Comment: I see, thank you for your answer, I had the same though but why in my first example does it work? I do the same thing, define a function in the interface, which references a mapping in the original contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that in your case it's an issue about `public` access modifier about the mapping that it don't read the data inside quote mapping.
For solve this issue, you can remove the access modifier from mapping, then you can create 'manually' your getter function inside Create smart contract and put signature about this method inside ICreate interface.
This is an example:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract Create {

    struct Quote {
        string quote;
        bool exists;
    }

    mapping(uint256 => Quote) quote;

    function set(uint256 ID) external {
        quote[ID] = Quote("quote", true);    
    }

    function getQuote(uint256 ID) external view returns(Quote memory) {
        return quote[ID];
    }
}

interface ICreate {
    struct Quote {
        string quote;
        bool exists;
    }

    function getQuote(uint256 ID) external view returns (Quote memory);

    function set(uint256 ID) external;
}

contract MyContract {
    function setQuote(address CreateAddress, uint256 ID) external {
        ICreate(CreateAddress).set(ID);
    }

    function getQuote(address CreateAddress, uint256 ID) external view returns (ICreate.Quote memory _quote) {
        _quote = ICreate(CreateAddress).getQuote(ID);
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you for your time, I will try it..  I'll think more about what you said and come back later, but I believe that's it.
I've seen this approach in other examples, I just didn't understand very well if it should be mandatory, I just wanted to make my contract cleaner, but all the places I looked for reference do it like this, so heheh, thank you very much.